# Too light background for solaris scheme in Vim using zsh

Tags: vim, zsh, gnome-terminal

I want to use [solarized](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized), which gives a decent color scheme in Vim. It works by setting the 16 colors ansi colors in the [gnome-terminal](https://github.com/sigurdga/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized). It works fine if I use Vim from bash, but in zsh the colors are off. Some letters have the right background, but most have too light background. What is it about zsh that interferes with the ansi colors as displayed by Vim?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this - if this is still an issue, perhaps giving relevant sections of `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`, `~/.vimrc` etc might help.

I'm using the [Solarized `vim` colorscheme](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized), and the [linked Gnome-Terminal](https://github.com/sigurdga/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized) settings in the following screenshots. As you can see, they appear to be identical - there's certainly no color issues in either `zsh` or `vim` that I've noticed (I don't use `bash` much).

My `zsh` settings are taken from [`oh-my-zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), and my prompt is a hacked-up version of [Phil!'s ZSH prompt](http://aperiodic.net/phil/prompt/) (I have messed with the coloring of Phil!'s ZSH prompt, because it didn't play well with the Solarized iTerm2 colors). However, I do not think I've messed with anything that would affect the Solarized colorings between `bash` and `zsh` in `vim`. Certainly the `vim` settings are identical between the two screenshots below.

[image: <code>vim</code> in Bash using Solarized colorings, light background] 
[image: <code>vim</code> in Zsh using Solarized colorings, light background]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 14 with zsh.

This fixed it (in the .vimrc)

```
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
set background=light
colorscheme solarized
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a veeery old question but I had the same problem and came across this so I thought it could still be useful to someone if I answered it.

For me `TERM` was not set to `xterm-256color` in `zsh` like it was in `bash` so the colours were messed up in `vim`.
Simply adding `export TERM=xterm-256color` to the `.zshrc` file fixed the problem.